# Transform assignments to dict

Tags: python

I have hard typed lots of assignments:

```
definition = ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames']
condition = ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount']
.
.
.
```

Intend to transform them to dict avoiding repeating typing:

```
{'definition': ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames'],
 'condition': ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount'] ...}
```

I tried to encapsulate them in class.

```
class OsPath:
    definition = ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames']
    condition = ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount']
```

Working on console

```
In [125]: dt = dict(vars(OsPath))
In [127]: {i:dt[i] for i in dt if not i.startswith('__')}
Out[127]:
{'condition': ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount'],
 'definition': ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames']}
```

How to do it in shortcut?

Comment: Like you've just shown... what are you asking exactly?

Comment: `d = {'definition': defintion, 'condition': condition}`, do not shadow `dict`

Comment: I am editting now

Comment: Please refer to edited question @JonClements

Comment: Not to be like this, but in what situation will you need this that you can just create the dictionary manually?

Comment: no dict in Javascript and it  treat object as dict. use the data in python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
definition = ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames']
condition = ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount']
d = {'definition': definition, 'condition': condition }
```

Note that you should avoid using the variable name `dict`, which is a builtin object.

But to be honest, what you're trying to do is not good practice if you're doing this at scale. You should rethink the design of your object.

Comment: There would be huge typing if more assignments

Comment: This is not a good design, especially if you have many assignments. I would  encourage you to rethink about your class design, and re-organize your data directly in dict, rather than class members.

Comment: why downvoting this? the _question_ isn't very good, but the answer is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you want:

```
definition = ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames']
condition = ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount']

result = {i: globals()[i] for i in ['definition', 'condition']}
```

Comment: There would be huge typing if more assignments

Comment: Where do you get these variables from?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleNamespace`

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
sn = SimpleNamespace(
definition = ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames'],
condition = ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount'],
)
```

It outputs:

```
In [44]: sn
Out[44]: namespace(condition=['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount'], definition=['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames'])

In [45]: vars(sn)
Out[45]:
{'condition': ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount'],
 'definition': ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames']}

In [17]: dict(definition = ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames'],condition = ['isabs', 'isdir'
    ...: , 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount'])
Out[17]: 
{'definition': ['basename', 'dirname', 'supports_unicode_filenames'],
 'condition': ['isabs', 'isdir', 'isfile', 'islink', 'ismount']}
```